# group by and concatenate values by group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
'dep': ["NYC", "PAR", "MAD"],
'arr': ["PAR", "SYD", "BCN"],
'ID': ["idx1", "idx1", "idx2"],
'step':[1, 2, 1]})

  dep  arr   ID  step
  NYC  PAR  idx1     1
  PAR  SYD  idx1     2
  MAD  BCN  idx2     1
```

I want to add a column "itinerary" that groups the data by "ID" (it's the "key"), and tells the itinerary according to the `step` column without aggregating the rows.

So the output would be :

```
  dep  arr   ID  step    itinerary
  NYC  PAR  idx1     1  NYC-PAR-SYD
  PAR  SYD  idx1     2  NYC-PAR-SYD
  MAD  BCN  idx2     1      MAD-BCN
```

I started trying with `df.groupby('ID')`, and then sorting by `step`, but I haven't figured out how to create a value according to two columns from two different rows (the arr of one is the dep of the other), how to concatenate the values for all rows of the group ?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try via `groupby()`, `map()`, `agg()` and `join()`:

```
df['itinerary']=  (df['ID'].map(df.groupby('ID')[['dep','arr']]
                 .agg(list)
                 .sum(1)
                 .agg(lambda x:list(set(x))[::-1]).str.join('-')))
```

output of `df`:

```
    dep     arr     ID      step    itinerary
0   NYC     PAR     idx1    1       NYC-PAR-SYD
1   PAR     SYD     idx1    2       NYC-PAR-SYD
2   MAD     BCN     idx2    1       MAD-BCN
```

### Update:

I don't think it is efficient but will do the job:

```
#run the above code first

check=(df['ID'].map(df.groupby('ID')[['dep','arr']]
                 .agg(list)
                 .sum(1)
                 .agg(lambda x:list(x)[::-1]).str.join('-')))

splited=check.str.split('-')

#in this code we don't used set so basically it's for comparision

cond=(splited.str.len().eq(4))  &  (splited.str[0]==splited.str[-1])
```

Finally:

```
df.loc[cond,'itinerary']=splited.str[-1]+'-'+df.loc[cond,'itinerary']
```

Comment: Output doesn't match since `set` will change the order

Comment: @AnuragDabas It works for almost every trip in my table. Indeed, there are trips that does something like a round trip with steps (like : NYC-PAR-SYD-NYC), these are the kind of trips where your solution doesn't work. Do you have an idea how could I fix it? I've tried many but still can't figure it out.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Awans I think that was because in a round trip with steps (like : NYC-PAR-SYD-NYC) there is repetation of `NYC` so we are using `set` that don't allow duplicates so that's why you are getting like this (like : NYC-PAR-SYD)

Comment: @AnuragDabas Do you have an idea on how to fix it ?

Comment: @Awans Updated answer...I think this should work ***:)***

Comment: @AnuragDabas Thanks for your help! I don't have the first step (I got "PAR-SYD-NYC" but I want "NYC-PAR-SYD-NYC")

Comment: Now try...changed this step:`df.loc[cond,'itinerary']=splited.str[-1]+'-'+df.loc[cond,'itinerary']`

Answer (score 0):

Groupby `ID` then convert each `dep` and `arr` columns to list, finally add them to get a single list, but while adding check if the item already exists in `dep` column for given index, you can use list comprehension for that, and finally join the strings, rename the column, at last `merge` the it back to original dataframe.

```py
result = (
            df.merge(df.groupby(['ID'])
            .apply(lambda row: '-'.join(list(row['dep']) + [item for item in row['arr'] if item not in list(row['dep'])] ))
            .reset_index()
            .rename(columns={0:'itinerary'})
                     )
        )
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
   dep  arr    ID  step    itinerary
0  NYC  PAR  idx1     1  NYC-PAR-SYD
1  PAR  SYD  idx1     2  NYC-PAR-SYD
2  MAD  BCN  idx2     1      MAD-BCN
```

You can then change the column name.